# Segregate stock data given in 1 minute intervals to 5 minute intervals given in format hour:min:second

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, stock

I want to change the time interval of the stock data given in 1 minute intervals to 5 minute intervals given in format hour:min:second. I am using pandas dataframe to load the prices in pandas from excel sheet.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [reprex].

Comment: So just take the 5 minute values or do you want an average of the munutes between?

Comment: @SolarMike Open of first and close of last, max value of all the intervals in between as high and min value of all the intervals as low.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your dataframe or expected output looks like it's hard to know exactly what you're looking for but you could probably do something like this:

```
import datetime as dt

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Generate data by minute for 10 hours
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': pd.date_range("11:00", "21:00", freq="1min")})
df['Price'] = np.round(np.random.random(df.shape[0]) * 100,2)

# Filter the price by minutes divisible by 5
df.loc[df.Time.dt.minute % 5 == 0]
```

Output:

```
    Time                Price
0   2021-06-16 11:00:00 43.84
5   2021-06-16 11:05:00 87.17
10  2021-06-16 11:10:00 52.89
15  2021-06-16 11:15:00 60.25
20  2021-06-16 11:20:00 92.36
... ... ...
610 2021-06-16 21:10:00 28.15
615 2021-06-16 21:15:00 60.86
620 2021-06-16 21:20:00 15.95
625 2021-06-16 21:25:00 4.17
630 2021-06-16 21:30:00 0.68
```